# Integrating SMS Broadcast Listener with React Native App for Background Processing

Tags: android, react-native, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on a React Native application where I need to integrate an SMS listener that can run even when the app is closed. I've already made an attempt with native code and related React Native modules, but the code don't seem to work, whenever a sms is received on the broadcast it is not seem to be received by the broadcast listner.I don't know if it is a receiver registration problem or something else.

Here is my code for better understanding. I have created a Java CLASS inside ...java/com/android_sms_listner , here's the code .

```
public class SMSListenerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public SMSListenerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "SMSListener";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startSMSListener() {
        Toast.makeText(reactContext, "SMS recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(reactContext, "SMS recieved on reciever", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    if (pdus != null) {
                        for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                            String messageBody = sms.getMessageBody();
                            String sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                            sendEvent("onSMSReceived", messageBody, sender);
                            Toast.makeText(reactContext, "SMS recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void show() {
        Toast.makeText(reactContext, "Hi from Module file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Show", "From show");
    }

    private void sendEvent(String eventName, String message, String sender) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, message);

        Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, SMSListnerHeadlessTask.class);
        intent.putExtra("messageBody", message);
        intent.putExtra("sender", sender);
        reactContext.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And i've created a SMSListenerPackage.java class in order to add the SMSListenerModule.java class in react packages. Here's the code of that file .

```
public class SMSListenerPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new SMSListenerModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

And then i am adding this package class in my MainApplication.java files . As such

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for
      // example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new SMSListenerPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

And the broadcast listener is registered inside the AndroidManifest.xml file inside <application>

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.android_sms_listner.SMSListener"
    android:exported="false"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here i am also initiating required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

In order to call the JavaScript file when a sms is received i have created a java class

```
public class SMSListnerHeadlessTask extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Override
    protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        WritableMap data = Arguments.createMap();
        Log.d("MyApp", "Custom Java file is running.");

        if (extras != null) {
            String messageBody = extras.getString("messageBody");
            String sender = extras.getString("sender");
            data.putString("messageBody", messageBody);
            data.putString("sender", sender);
        }

        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
                "SMSListenerTask", // Task name, must match your JavaScript module name
                data,
                5000, // Timeout for the task in milliseconds
                true // Task can run in parallel
        );
    }
}
```

And the js file as such

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'

const SMSListenerTask = async (taskdata) =>{
    const {messageBody,sender} = taskdata
    console.warn(`Recieved SMS from ${sender} : ${messageBody}`)
    console.warn("Was called")
}

module.exports = NativeModules.SMSListener;
```

And registering the js file as headless task in index.js

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask("SMSListenerTask",()=>require("./SMSListenerTask"))
```

Please provide guidance on any improvements or corrections needed to make this integration work . Thank you so much !